# как в centos 7 добавить больше 1000 рандомных IPv6 с маской /64

Tags: linux, centos, ipv6

хостер выдал подсеть 2a05:fb40:5::/48, в этой сети 65000 сетей с маской /64

Соответственно интересуют два вопроса:

- как сгенерировать по 5-6 IPv6 из всех 65000 подсетей.
- в каким формате и куда добавить получившиеся ip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

два подвопроса:

1. получить список шестнадцатиричных чисел от `0001` до `ffff` можно, например, так:

   ```
   $ for i in $(seq 1 65535); do printf '%04x\n' $i; done
   ```
2. ip-адреса закрепляются за указанным сетевым интерфейсом программой *ip*:

   ```
   $ sudo ip address add ip-адрес/маска dev интерфейс
   ```

   (и `address` и `add` можно сократить до одной буквы: `ip a a ...`)

   удаляются аналогично:

   ```
   $ sudo ip address del ip-адрес/маска dev интерфейс
   ```

   (`del` здесь тоже можно сократить до одной буквы `ip a d ...`)

объединив их вместе, получим что-нибудь вроде:

```
#!/bin/bash
prefix="2a05:fb40:5:"
mask=64
addrs="1 2 3 4 5"
interface="eth0"

for i in $(seq 1 65535); do
  for j in $addrs; do
    a=$(printf '%s%04x::%s/%s' $prefix $i $j $mask)
    ip a a $a dev $interface
  done
done
```

запускать скрипт (присвоив файлу бит исполнимости) надо от имени пользователя *root*:

```
$ sudo /путь/к/этому/скрипту
```

им будут сгенерированы и выполнены такого вида команды:

```
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0001::1/64 dev eth0
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0001::2/64 dev eth0
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0001::3/64 dev eth0
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0001::4/64 dev eth0
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0001::5/64 dev eth0
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0002::1/64 dev eth0
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0002::2/64 dev eth0
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0002::3/64 dev eth0
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0002::4/64 dev eth0
ip a a 2a05:fb40:5:0002::5/64 dev eth0
...
```

---

но запускать его лично я бы не рискнул — попытка закрепить это огромное количество адресов (и автоматически добавляемых маршрутов — по одному на каждый адрес) — `5*65535=327675` — вполне вероятно, довольно скоро превысит какие-нибудь лимиты сетевой подсистемы программы *linux*, что может привести к перезагрузке системы (или потребовать её для восстановления нормального функционирования).